# Why can't I propose a tag synonym on [customization]?

Tags: support, bug, tags, tag-synonyms

I tried to suggest the synonym [user-preferences](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-preferences) → [customization](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/customization), but received this confusing error:

[image]

I don't see any synonym proposals on [user-preferences](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-preferences).. Was a synonym proposed on [preferences](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/preferences), which was then synonymized with [user-preferences](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-preferences)?

What is going on here?

Comment: I see you're using your new theme... ;) +1 for that!

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Ha :) The normal site looks strange whenever I see it now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that was the reason. There was a relationship between [preferences](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/preferences) and [user-preferences](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-preferences) it seems. I went ahead and made both [preferences](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/preferences) and [user-preferences](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-preferences) a synonym of [customization](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/customization) and merged all previous questions into that.

Comment: Is there a way to view information of a synonymized tag? I tried, but always ended up getting redirected to the parent tag..

Comment: @gandalf3 I have access to different tools than you so i'm not sure. In any case the system restricts you, just let a mod know.